# SQL query works in MariaDB console but not in python pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, pymysql

My SQL query works in **MariaDB** CLI but do not work in python **pymysql**.

#### My requirements:

I want to get the number of the record(**COUNT(*)**) with same username, and then get the **rank**(rowNo) for each user, if two usernames have same records (**COUNT(*)**), the **rank**(rowNo) will also be same(@rowNo:=@rowNo).

#### Issue:

Below SQL works in **MariaDB** CLI, the same number of record has same rank(rowNo). But in python pymysql, the same number of reocord has different rank(rowNO), it will increase(@rowNo:=@rowNo+1). Why?

```
        art_sql = "SELECT T2.rowNo, T2.username, T2.art_number                        \
               FROM                                                               \
               (SELECT T1.art_number,                                             \
                       T1.username,                                               \
                       IF(@c=T1.art_number,@rowNo:=@rowNo,@rowNo:=@rowNo+1) AS rowNo, \
                       @c:=T1.art_number                                          \
               FROM                                                               \
                 (                                                                \
                   SELECT username,COUNT(*) AS art_number                         \
                   FROM %s                                                        \
                   GROUP BY username                                              \
                   ORDER BY art_number DESC                                       \
                 )T1                                                              \
               )T2, (SELECT @rowNo:=0,@c:=0)T3                                    \
               WHERE T2.username='%s';"                                           \
               % (self.__article_table, username)
```

BTW, I have a similar SQL below do not have this issue:

```
        rev_sql = "SELECT T2.rowNo, T2.username, T2.total_revenue                     \
               FROM                                                               \
               (SELECT T1.total_revenue,                                          \
                       T1.username,                                               \
                       IF(@c=T1.total_revenue,@rowNo:=@rowNo,@rowNo:=@rowNo+1) AS rowNo, \
                       @c:=T1.total_revenue                                       \
               FROM                                                               \
                 (                                                                \
                   SELECT username,SUM(money) AS total_revenue                    \
                   FROM %s                                                        \
                   GROUP BY username                                              \
                   ORDER BY total_revenue DESC                                    \
                 )T1                                                              \
               )T2, (SELECT @rowNo:=0,@c:=0)T3                                    \
               WHERE username='%s';"                                              \
               % (self.__article_table, username)
```

Could you please help for answer this? Thanks~

Comment: Perhaps you need `DENSE_RANK`?

Answer (score 0):

IF(@c=T1.total_revenue,@rowNo:=@rowNo,@rowNo:=@rowNo+1) AS rowNo, \
                       @c:=T1.total_revenue 
try 
 IF(@c=T1.total_revenue,@rowNo:=@rowNo,@rowNo:=@rowNo+1) AS rowNo, \
                       (@c:=T1.total_revenue)